# Customize AWS managed Grafana workspace URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, grafana

I am creating a managed AWS Grafana worspace using [this Teraform module](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-managed-service-grafana).

The workspace URL is randomly generated when the workspace is created. Same behaviour whether I use Terraform or the AWS console. So instead of this URL:

```
   https://g-tz999ee66.grafana-workspace.region.amazonaws.com
```

I would like to get:

```
   https://my_defined_workspace_id.grafana-workspace.region.amazonaws.com
```

I would like to know how I can customise the Grafana workspace URL.

Comment: I don't think that's possible at this time: https://github.com/aws/amazon-managed-grafana-roadmap/issues/6.